# Passing parent state as prop to all components inside {children} | Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to give access to all `{children}` components to use or modify the state inside the parent component here is the code:

**parent component:**

```
export function FormStep({ children }) {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(null);

  return (
    <ul
      className={
        "pointer-events-none absolute flex translate-x-[200px] flex-col justify-between gap-7 opacity-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out"
      }
    >
      {children} //all children here need to access 'activeStep'
    </ul>
  );
}
```

i want all the `{children}` components to access the `activeStep` state.

normally we can pass `activeStep` as a prop to the child of the parent

**like this:**

```
export function FormStep({ children }) {
      const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(null);
    
      return (
        <ul
          className={
            "pointer-events-none absolute flex translate-x-[200px] flex-col justify-between gap-7 opacity-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out"
          }
        >
          <Child isActive={activeStep}></Child>
        </ul>
      );
    }
```

i want the same result but for the `{children}` object

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [React.Children](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children) and [React.cloneElement](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement)

This should do the trick

```
export function FormStep({ children }) {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(null);
    
  return (
    <ul className="pointer-events-none absolute flex translate-x-[200px] flex-col justify-between gap-7 opacity-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out">    
      {React.Children.map(children, child => (
        React.cloneElement(child, { activeStep })
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```